# Why do linear algebra books have this cover?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

Why do many linear algebra books have covers like this? I think the one on Hadamard matrices hints at me that they are just representing the entries of the matrix as colors (hence why it is black and white in the Hadamard one). Although the Hadamard matrix one is the only one in which not all of the components are perfect rectangles, so perhaps something else is being captured. Does anyone have any idea as to what these covers are? Perhaps there is no common trend and I am just reading too much into it but I would like to know if someone has some insight.

Thank you in advance and best regards.

[image]

Comment: The first two seem somewhat symmetric along the diagonal, which to me is very reminiscent of something like a distance matrix from data science. That said, that matrix isn't really used like a matrix in linear algebra so I doubt this is what they were aiming at. Also this doesn't really help for the other two.

Comment: The one from Friedberg is a work of abstract art https://www.bauhaus.de/de/sammlung/highlights/207_textil/372 from decades before the book was published. Perhaps there was not a lot of significance behind it.

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: Have a great day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the preface of Matrix Analysis:

"The cover art for the second edition was the result of a lucky encounter on a Delta flight from Salt Lake City to Los Angeles in spring 2003. The young man in the middle seat said he was an artist who paints abstract paintings that are sometimes mathematically inspired. In the course of friendly conversation, he revealed that his special area of mathematical enjoyment was linear algebra, and that he had studied Matrix Analysis. After mutual expressions of surprise at the chance nature of our meeting, and a pleasant discussion, we agreed that appropriate cover art would enhance the visual appeal of the second edition; he said he would send something to consider. In due course a packet arrived from Seattle. It contained a letter and a stunning 4.5- by 5-inch color photograph, identified on the back as an image of a 72- by 66-inch oil on canvas, painted in 2002. The letter said that “the painting is entitled *Surprised Again on the Diagonal* and is inspired by the recurring prevalence of the diagonal in math whether it be in geometry, analysis, algebra, set theory or logic."

Comment: A Google search shows the Hadamard matrices that are represented by the cover of "Hadamard Matrices".